# get response from GET request to API

Tags: php, api, curl, get, response

I am trying to get response from api call,

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fm.transfer-to.com/cgi-bin/shop/topup');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo $response;
$status = curl_getinfo($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

// above code outputs nothing

I tried `file_get_contents()` , but

```
$url ="https://fm.transfer-to.com/cgi-bin/shop/topup";
$responses = split("\n", file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($responses as $response) {
    $key = split("=", $response)[0];
    $value= split("=", $response)[1];
    if($key != "" && $value != "") {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

It fails :   `failed to open stream: Connection timed out.`

How to get response from Api (API sends back plain text , not json) , When i request to above URL using form.

Comment: The end-point is an rest api, and it expects some token. Check what tokens are provided by the supplier and use then in the request as per documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This server on https has [only TLSv1 support and very limited and weak ciphers support only](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fm.transfer-to.com), I believe your PHP libraries are not negotiating over this configuration

to workaround this

- either make your PHP client support the stuff that these server supports (not recommended but only way if this server cannot update its configuration)
- go over http (not recommended) for sandbox purpose only

---

See

- [mcrypt-list-algorithms](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-list-algorithms.php)
- [openssl-get-cipher-methods](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php)